# Spinner OnItemSelected not working with custom row layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

I'm trying to use custom row layout for spinner as following:

```
String[] countryArr={"USA","Canada","Other"};
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.row, R.id.text, countryArr);
spinnerCountry.setAdapter(adapter);
```

---

**row.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/BLACK"
        android:textSize="26dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

**and java code:**

```
spinnerCountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener {

    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
            long id) {
        selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString().trim();
        Log.i("MyOnItemSelectedListener","selected ="+selected);

        }
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
        etCountry.setText("");
    Log.i("MyOnItemSelectedListener","nothing selected");
    }
}
```

When I start the app, I get this in the log: `"selected =Other"` because it is default.

But When I click spinner, I get the screen as shown below and `onItemSelected` doesn't work and hence that alert box is always displayed allowing to select all 3 values but not performing any action.

**main.xml**

```
<com.Mypackage.MySpinner
                    android:id="@+id/SpinnerCountry1"
                    android:layout_width="45dp"
                    android:layout_height="59dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="160dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/selector_slim_spinner"
                    android:clickable="true"
                    android:entries="@array/blankarray" />
```

---

```
public class MySpinner extends Spinner {

    private Context _context;

    public MySpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        _context = context;
    }

    public MySpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
        _context = context;
    }

    public MySpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context);
        _context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildAt(int index) {
        View v = new View(_context);
        return v;
    }

}
```

**Please note that** if I don't use custom row layout for spinner, `OnItemSelected` works fine.

Any help appreciated.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: why you post question second time ?

Comment: I deleted that as it was not quite clear and not well-formatted.

Comment: Why you use Radio Button in spinner? Spinner is select one selection at a time you dont need the radio button, You can select only one Item fron Spinner when you use the Spinner.

Comment: I know that. But it's one of the design requirements.

Comment: @GAMA Did you find out the solution? I am also stuck with the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

Change your row.xml to

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/BLACK"
    android:textSize="26dp"
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false" />

<RadioButton
    android:id="@+id/radio"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
    android:clickable="false"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and try

Comment: In summary, set all elements in the custom layout as `clickable="false"`. This works a treat!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to set a listener on your RadioButton with a custom ArrayAdapter ?

Comment: you mean `setOnCheckedChangeListener`?

Comment: I think a `setOnClickListener`would be better since your radiobuttons aren't in a radiogroup, i'm not sure that an `setOnCheckedChangeListener`would works, but you can try.
In custom arrayadapter something like 
`view.findViewById(R.id.radio);`

Answer (score 0):

I think, this might've done the job

After you initialized the spinner on your onCreate.

```
yourspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```